# php popup on mysql addion by another service

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, page-refresh

I currently have a caller ID program which logs all phone calls into a mySQL database via a service running on a linux server.  To view this I have a php page to parse the data and allow notes or comments to be entered or viewed.  Currently the page has to be manually refreshed when a new call comes in.  I could have the page automatically refresh after x number of seconds but I was hoping there maybe a way to have the page automatically refresh when a new entry is put in to the mySQL table?  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script to pull the DB every so often and parse any new results to JSON
Use Javascript to do an ajax call to that script on the server every x seconds and append new information to your list.